# Reduce spacing between bars in seaborn hist plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am plotting some data with

```
g = seaborn.displot(data, x=var, stat='probability')

# Set appropriate ticks                   
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, int(data[var].max() + 1), 1.0))
plt.show()
```

which is giving me the desired plot:

[image]

But I would like to compress the axis to remove the unnecessary space and I'm struggling to work out how.

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44222066/how-to-put-bars-close-to-each-other-in-a-seaborns-factorplot-when-comparing-1-v) and [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-remove-gaps-between-bars-in-matplotlib-bar-chart)  - maybe you'll find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the [`margins`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.margins.html) that determine the space added at both sides of the data limit to get the view limit. Default is `0.05`.

```
plt.margins(x=0.5)
```

[image]

---

As pointed out by *JohanC* in the comment below: if your data are discrete values you may specify `discrete=True` or cast your data to strings to plot them as categories (in the latter case you don't need to set the ticks manually).

```
sns.displot(data[var].astype(str), stat='probability')
```

[image]

Comment: The main problem is that OP forgot to add `discrete=True` for these discrete data.  A histogram default uses settings for continuous data,  which don't make sense here.

Comment: @JohanC: right, would you post this as an answer, so that I can delete my answer.

Comment: You can update yours

Comment: IMO prefer `discrete=True` over `.astype(str)` as the former generalizes across the different ways of invoking `displot`/`histplot`.

Comment: @mwaskom with `discrete=True` and numerical data you need to set the ticks as shown in the OP, see [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpUoa.png), whereas with categorical data you directly get a neatly formatted x-axis.

Comment: That's a good point. Well, either way, you don't need to pass `data` and `x=data[x_var]`.

Comment: @mwaskom yes, this was a leftover from the original example. Changed it in the answer, thanks.